# How to make new column in data frame using x,y index numbers of a second lookup dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, coordinates, lookup

I have two dataframes. The first is a lookup dataframe, which contains many variables. Example:

`Lookup <- data.frame(A = 1:7,B = 8:14)`

```
  A  B
1 1  8
2 2  9
3 3 10
4 4 11
5 5 12
6 6 13
7 7 14
```

The second contains output from a model, with two of the columns referencing the index of the lookup data frame. Example

`Model <- data.frame(Column = c(2,2), Row = c(7,4))`

```
  Column Row
1      2   7
2      2   4
```

For reference, I want another third column on the model data frame based on the indexes from the lookup data frame. Example:

```
  Column Row Lookup
1      2   7     14
2      2   4     11
```

I intended to add my lookup column with the following:

`Model$Lookup <- Lookup[Model$Row,Model$Column]`

However, 95% of the time when I run this code, many more columns are being added to the model data frame than I intended. I suspect that I'm adding as many columns as rows of data into my model data frame — the data that they include is from Lookup data frame but in a jumbled order.

The other 5% of the time I get just the one column, but 50% of the answers are correct. The rest of the data is seemingly copies of some of the correct answers.

This might be basic, but any help or thoughts anyone has would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use row/column indexing with `matrix`

```
Model$Lookup <- Lookup[as.matrix(Model[2:1])]
```

Comment: `transform(Model, Lookup = Lookup[cbind(Row, Column)])`

Comment: I’m very much a beginner. Could you explain why a matrix works in this instance?